# nginx how to configure route to html file?

Tags: nginx

I have the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/site/public;
    index main.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

At root directory I also have html files:page1.html, page2.html, page3.html.
I would like to configure route mysite.com/services/page1 to file page1.html. etc. How can I do it? 
I tried it:

```
location = /services/page1 { try_files /page1.html;}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rewrite url only if the file doesn't exist you can use named location in `try_files` directive.

```
location /services {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @service_pages;
}

location @service_pages {
    rewrite ^/services/page([1-3]).html /page$1.html;
}
```